# Fixed Size ImageView Shows Images in different sizes

Tags: android, imageview, android-volley, scaletype

I am working on an application where i have to download images from server, at server i have images of different form. like `jpeg`,`png`.

I am using `volley` to download my image

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
       android:layout_width="65dp"
       android:layout_height="65dp"
       android:id="@+id/main_profile_image" 
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
       android:background="#eeeeee"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

but my outcome comes in form 
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkZpb.png)
How to fix it. Any Help?

Comment: Change the `scaleType` to `centerCrop`.

Comment: fixed center adjust the image according to your height width and the image height width to maintain aspect ration its better to use center crop or fitxy

Comment: use this  android:adjustViewBounds="true" it will help

Answer (score 1):

try this it will help

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

becuase `scaleType="fitCenter"` is by default when you omit

see [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/clear-up-ambiguity-about-android-image-view-scale-types-with-this-guide/)

Comment: then better try to change image size from server with same height and width :(